# iOS Monacaデバッガー(3.2.0)でビューポートが効かない

Tags: javascript, ios, monaca

今週から（iOS Monacaデバッガー(3.2.0)になってから）、ビューポートが効かず、画面が4倍に表示されてしまいます。
もちろんiOSアプリにて「ビューポート制御を有効にする」は、チェックし、monaca.viewport({width : 640});を指定しています。
どなたか解決策、回避策があればご教示ください。
環境：iPhone6plus iOS:v8.1.2
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 画面のスクリーンショットを貼っていただける嬉しいです。

Comment: スクリーンショットありがとうございます。metaタグによる設定はどのようにされていますか？  
また、下記のような記述により表示は変わりますか？   
■monaca.viewportメソッドを使用  
`monaca.viewport({width : "device-width"})`  
■metaタグを使用  
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: user7461さん、ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘いただいたmetaタグは既に定義済でした。（説明不足で申し訳ございません）
monaca.viewportメソッドを削除しても状況に変化はありませんでした。。
なお、手元にあったiPhone4sではmonaca3.1.1、3.2.0とも正しく表示されました。

Comment: user7461さん、確認したところデバッグビルドしたアプリは正常に表示されました。同じアプリをmonacaデバッガからの実行ではやはり大きく表示されました。

Comment: カスタムビルド版デバッガー(cordova3.5)で確認したところプリは正常に表示されましたので、monacaデバッガー3.2.0(cordova3.7.0)では正しく動作しないようです・・・。

Comment: 下記の環境で、monaca.viewportをコメントアウトしたら正常に表示されました。metaタグは上記に記載したものを使用しています。上記に記載したメタタグを使用しても4倍に表示されますでしょうか？
【検証環境】
iOS8.1.2　　
monacaデバッガー3.2.0(cordova3.7.0)

Answer (score 1):

テンプレート「Hello Worldアプリ」で試したところ、同様の不具合が再現しました。

この不具合への対処方法は、monaca.viewportをコメントアウトして、下記のmetaタグを挿入することで解決しました。

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

【コメントアウト前】
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

【コメントアウト後】
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]